# Select records with specific date

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access 2007 I'm trying to select all the records in table that have the same date in a field.
I get the date from a textbox on the report, txtDate.
I'm getting either syntax error or to few parameters, expected 2. I tried different format functions as suggested on the net without much success.

```
select * from tbl where odatsa = #" & Me.txtDate & "#"
```

Comment: I've got a stupid workaround whereI select everything and use if sentence to compare rs!odatsa with me.txtdate. Works, but there is a better way!

Comment: it's date/time, debug says #16. 05. 2016#

Comment: Instead of using a text box, could you use the active X date picker? Or is that what this field is?

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Jet SQL are in Month/Day/Year format. if your regional settings are different, you should modify the date in VBA:

```
Public Function SQLDate(dt As DateFalse) As String
    SQLDate = "#" & Month(dt) & "/" & Day(dt) & "/" & Year(dt) & "#"
End Function
```

and use it:

```
select * from tbl where odatsa = " & SQLDate(Me.txtDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Going with marlan's suggestion, this does the trick.
I wish working with dates would be more intuitive

```
"select * from tbl where odatsa= " & Format(Me.txtDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"))
```

Comment: Intuitive or not, you have to play by the rules.